# Draw a line under button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, line

I am trying to draw a line under the button, well in fact, last element within the button. The button has three element inside in vertical: image, label, and finally the line I am trying to put. Line must be the same widht than button. Below the code that is not working (line does not appear):

```
            <Button Name="btnDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,10" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Height="36" Width="36" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/MyResources;component/PNG/Delete.png"/>
                            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Delete</Label>
                            <Line Stroke="Orange" X1="0" Y1="25" X2="{Binding ElementName=btnDelete, Path=Width}" Y2="25" />                                
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

Comment: The X2 binding should be `X2="{Binding ElementName=btnDelete, Path=ActualWidth}`. However, using a Line for this purpose is impractical.

Comment: and what other component do you propose, a rectangle?

Comment: Your solution works.

Comment: `<Rectangle Height="1" Fill="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>`. It's hardly ever necessary to bind an element's size to the size of another element

Comment: @Clemens thanks again, for your support. As said your solution is also valid and works.

Comment: Why downvote? Could someone explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a straight `Line` then use a `Border`. If you just need it horizontal then use it like :

```
<Button Name="btnDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,10" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="0 0 0 3">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Height="36" Width="36" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/MyResources;component/PNG/Delete.png"/>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Delete</Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Use `Margin` and `Padding` to adjust it - when needed.

Also u should use `Paths` instead of `Image`. You can convert them directly in `XAML`-`Paths` with Incscape.

**Additional Information** `Path`

A `Path` is a good way to show Icons in XAML. They can look like:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Gray"
        Data="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
```

You can give them different `Brushes` and they scale very well in the most scenarious. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/de/) has a good feature - to create the `Path` out of your `Image` (svg / png / jpg etc).

There are also `Icon-Packs` that allready have them like font awesome.

Comment: Working. Thanks! regarding paths instead of Image, do you mean, <Image Source="{Binding SourceUri}"></Image> and then public string SourceUri
{
    get
    {
        return Path.Combine(GetApplicationFolder(), "Resources/image.jpg");
    }
}

Comment: I gave you additional information in updated answer. Please mark me as answered.

Comment: It is just a vector description of your image. Of course u cant use it to show image files. You can use for example an Arrow.png within an `Image` or a `Path` that contains some `M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I have just been playing with paths right now and I have seen that paths are useful to make different types of free shapes. I think you refer that one can create his owns custom free shapes and then no need to use icons, right? Of course, you must have imagination to do this and get amazing shapes.

Comment: Yes and u don't need much imagination - you just need an image and use for example `Incscape` to generate `XAML` from an Image. Incscape is a tool and you can find a tutorial http://blog.tiaan.com/link/2009/02/21/vectorize-bitmaps-to-xaml-using-potrace-inkscape

Comment: I like to keep my Icons in Theme Colors - so they change for example when the user switches his Window from light to dark. `Paths` have a changeable color - Images don't. So giving them themed ressources as colors have a cool effect ! :) !